# Correct HTTP status code for a not satisfiable REST request

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I currently develop a task queue with a RESTful API.

In order to handle a task, a worker has to create a lease.

```
PUT .../leases
```

If the task queue has tasks available, this will succeed, a lease will be created and the server responds with status `201`.

I am unsure how to handle this case when no tasks are available. It is not possible to create a lease, when no tasks are available. Which HTTP status code would be appropriate for this case?

- `204 No Content` - The client hasn't made anything wrong, but there is no data.
- `400 Bad Request` - This is imho not applicable, as it means "the request could not be understood by the server", which is not the case

In the meantime I thought that this approach might not be ideal. Either I use `503`, as recommended of Brian and also backed by a passage of [REST in practice](http://restinpractice.com), or I change the whole process.

I was thinking of leases which could be created tentatively. That means

1. `PUT` to `/leases`
2. Either create a lease, assign a task and respond with `201` or create a tentative lease and respond with `202`
3. Tentative leases will stay for some time. If tasks gets available, they are assigned to the tentative leases. If there is no task for a specific period of time, the lease gets deleted and the server will respond with `410`
4. The client should then start again with 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the resource is controlled by the server and there's nothing the client can do to influence the outcome, a 500-range code would be most appropriate.

`503 - Service Unavailable` sounds right to me. It implies that the server has not got enough resources available to meet the needs of the request. You should probably also return a meaningful error in the body of the response to make it explicitly clear that it failed because no leases/tasks were available, but that might not be the case sometime in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`404 - Not Found` could be used. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) summarizes it as:

> The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

Comment: I don't like the notion of telling, the resource is not there, as it is existing. Maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: One way to look at it is if you try to view a page on a blog that doesn't exist you would get a 404. If that page than gets created it would no longer be a 404. It still isn't an exact fit but I don't think any of them are.

Answer (score 1):

404 almost works, but I think of it as the resource you are dealing with and you are doing a PUT to create a resource. Of course it doesn't exist that's why you are creating it.

I would agree with your first thought on the 400 Bad Request in a narrow sense of the definition. But if you broaden the definition to include anything that could go wrong with the request then it would fit your situation and I think it's acceptable to do just that. For example we send a 400 back if the request didn't meet the schema we were expecting and if there are validation errors on the resource. For our service if we can programmatic determine that this is a bad request we send back a 400.

For your service the creation of a lease when no tasks are available constitutes a bad request, and you can send the 400 with text explaining what the problems is. I think the 400 was meant for a broader definition then what you are holding it to.

I don't think the 500's work because they are more unhandled stuff, and this is a case you can handle and provide informational responses to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IIS sends a 405 Method Not Allowed if I try to use an unsupported method (ie PUT when it expects a GET).  And it sends a 404 Not Found if the endpoint doesn't exist at all.